# Add and sort created nodes form JavaScript into a HTML table without JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html

first of all please notice, I'm new here and I'm not a program expert.

What I want: I made a stopwatch in JavaScript/HTML/CSS and it's working.
Now I want to save the name which can be written in a textfield (HTML) and the time after I hit the save button into the table in the HTML file. But I would like to have sorted it by time.

My Problem: I can save the the names and times into the table. But I can't sort it directly after smashing the safe button. I'm not an expert and I never used JQuery. So, is there another way to sort this table immediately without any Plug-Ins?

Below you see the function which saves the time and the name into the table and after that set the time to 0.

I also added the code the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dtq6o52h/

But please notice, that there is one file missing in fiddle (the main.js)

Unfortunately i don't know how to add a second file into js fiddle. The code for the main.js file you also can see below.

Thank you, regards

McMauser

Function from stopwatch.js

```
this.reset = function() {
  var playername = document.getElementById("name").value;

  var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

  //
  var newRow = table.insertRow(1);

  var cel1 = newRow.insertCell(0)
  var cel2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
  var cel3 = newRow.insertCell(2);

  cel1.innerHTML = id;
  cel2.innerHTML = playername;
  cel3.innerHTML = timeFormatter(time);


  id++;
  time = 0;
  update();
  console.log(id);
};
this.isOn = false;
}
```

main.js

```
var timer = document.getElementById('timer');
var toggleBtn = document.getElementById('toggle');
var resetBtn = document.getElementById('reset');
var watch = new Stopwatch(timer);

function start() {
  toggleBtn.textContent = 'Stop';
  watch.start();
}

function stop() {
  toggleBtn.textContent = 'Start';
  watch.stop();
}

toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  watch.isOn ? stop() : start();
});

resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  watch.reset();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> So, is there another way to sort this table immediately without any
>   Plug-Ins?

Yes! Click on headers to sort data:

```js
(function(w) {
 w.data = [
  { column1: "CCC", column2: "111", column3: "EEE" },
  { column1: "AAA", column2: "BBB", column3: "CCC" }
 ];

    w.sortData = function(columnName) {
   w.data = w.data.sort((a, b) => ((a[columnName] < b[columnName]) ? -1 : ((a[columnName] > b[columnName]) ? 1 : 0)));
  render();
 }

 w.render = function() {
     var trs = data.map(a => `<tr><td>${a.column1}</td><td>${a.column2}</td><td>${a.column3}</td></tr>`).join('');
          document.querySelector("#myTable tbody").innerHTML = trs;
 }
})(window);
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th onclick="sortData('column1');">Header 1</th>
   <th onclick="sortData('column2');">Header 2</th>
   <th onclick="sortData('column3');">Header 3</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But i thought more about: i click the save button and the time is saved where it should be stored.

Like I have      Albert      1:345
                       Berta       1:700

And then add  Certa with 1:600 automatically between this two values like:

                       Albert      1:345
                       Certa       1:600
                       Berta       1:700

Is there also a way to do something like that?

BTW i oriented myself with this tutorial on youtube.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRhB1IG7uAw&t=1001s